# Optimizing JVM and Java compiler for short programs (e.g. utilities)

Tags: java, maven, optimization, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm working on optimizing our CI/CD. One of the parts is optimizing Maven builds. The only things I've found so far that helped me to speed up build x2 are setting Maven options to

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1"
```

and running Maven in parallel using 2 threads per CPU:

```
mvn -T 2C install
```

I'm using Oracle JDK 8 and I wonder if there are any JVM options might be used to tune JVM itself (as Java is primary for high load long running servers but not utilities I assume)? Also maybe there some options for `javac` might be helpful? Thank you very much for any suggestions and help!

Comment: First if you use `-T 2C` this means 2 * Number of Core (C) which results in the number of threads...The question is what is really the problem of your maven build? How many module do you have? How many tests are you running ?

Comment: Echoing @khmarbaise, I would contend that there is some else wrong with your build if the actual compile/build time is your problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise please, see [here](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-maven-build-is-slow-speed-it-up/) it says it is number of threads per core. there are 14 modules and I'm currently optimizing just build, without tests. it builds in 2.5 minutes but we want it to take less time:)

Comment: @Erik it is not a problem, I'm just optimizing the things where it is possible. build without tests takes 2.5 minutes and I was able to speed it up to 1 minutes but I want more if possible:)

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich The explanations in link you have given is simply wrong, cause the [code in Java can not control how many threads per core are running](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.java;h=c7e5d9ee3545a72d218a4d17bf53fd831fe78c3c;hb=HEAD#l1582). Furthermore I would suggest to check your build with [maven-buildtime-profiler](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-buildtime-profiler) and see where the real time issues are really be...Apart from that I would check the time with `-T 2`, than with `T 4` ...

Comment: I would assume using `-T 2C` is too much...better use smaller values, cause the parallelisation related to the threading strategy used in Maven which is based on per module level which can be run in dependency levels....so based on the low number of modules i think 2 or maybe 4 threads might be a good start...you can furthermore try `-T 6` where I have my doubts that it will be faster...Another thing based on the low number of modules I think things like tests could be an issue and transfers to repository etc.. Make a check with profiler....

Comment: Another thing comes to my mind? Do you really need `mvn install` or would `mvn package` sufficient? Which Maven version are you running? Using the most recent versions of the maven plugins?

Comment: @khmarbaise ok then, thanks.. but what do they mean [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)? Maybe I misunderstand something. I was trying -T1C but it worked x2 worse. my machine have 4 physical cores and 8 logical. Regarding profiler - I will take a look, cool! but I've tried [this one](https://github.com/takari/maven-profiler) on the module building the most of time and it was mostly compiling, aspectj and generating java classes from wsdl. I'm using Maven 3.5 and other things seem to be pretty new (Spring Boot, Spring Data, Spring Mvc and etc.)

Comment: The expression `1 thread per cpu core` is misleading cause the ´per cpu core` just means multiplied by ...see the code reference I've given(Think i should change that description)..and yes you can use takari life cycle...also an option...